# New Kendo app throwing error in React app

Tags: reactjs, npm, kendo-ui, npm-scripts

The error displayed is

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-popup/index.mjs
```

I followed these instructions from https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/getting-started/

```
npx create-kendoreact-app
```

Below is my configuration

> ? What is the name of your project? demoapp
>
> ? Do you want to use TypeScript? No
>
> ? Do you want to use SASS? Yes
>
> ? Which Kendo UI Theme do you want to use?
>
> ❯ default
>
> bootstrap
>
> material

after this i entered the directory and performed

```
npm i
npm run start
```